# Why is this CSV form letter code incompatible with the table of contents in ConTeXt?

Tags: table-of-contents, context, chapters, context-mkiv, csv

Using the code in the answer to [How to create form letters from spreadsheet data in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72735/how-to-create-form-letters-from-spreadsheet-data-in-context), I am building a document from data in a CSV file. I found that some part of the code is incompatible with chapter titles, such that, if I add a table of contents using `\completecontent` or add headers using `\getmarkings{chapter}`, it will not compile.

```
% macros=mkvi

\unprotect
\startluacode
  local datasets = { }

  local buffersraw   = buffers.raw
  local context      = context
  local ioloaddata   = io.loaddata
  local lpegmatch    = lpeg.match
  local stringformat = string.format
  local stringmatch  = string.match
  local stringsub    = string.sub
  local tableconcat  = table.concat
  local tableswapped = table.swapped

  local die = function (msg) print(msg or "ERROR") os.exit(1) end

  local csv_parser
  do
    --- This is (more than) an RFC 4180 parser.
    --- http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
    local C, Cg, Cs, Ct, P, S, V
        = lpeg.C, lpeg.Cg, lpeg.Cs, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.P, lpeg.S, lpeg.V

    local backslash = P[[\letterbackslash]]
    local comma     = ","
    local dquote    = P[["]]
    local eol       = S"\n\r"^1
    local noquote   = 1 - dquote
    local unescape  = function (s) return stringsub(s, 2) end
    csv_parser = P{
      "file",
      file    = Ct((V"header" * eol)^-1 * V"records"),
      header  = Cg(Ct(V"name" * (comma * V"name")^0), "header"),
      records = V"record" * (eol * V"record")^0 * eol^0,
      record  = Ct(V"field" * (comma * V"field")^0),
      name    = V"field",
      field   = V"escaped" + V"non_escaped",
      --- Deviate from rfc: the “textdata” terminal was defined only
      --- for 7bit ASCII. Also, any character may occur in a quoted
      --- field as long as it is escaped with a backslash. (\TEX          --- macros start with two backslashes.)
      escaped     = dquote
                  * Cs(((backslash * 1 / unescape) + noquote)^0)
                  * dquote
                  ,
      non_escaped = C((1 - dquote - eol - comma)^0),
    }
  end

  local process = function (id, raw)
    --- buffers may have trailing EOLs
    raw = stringmatch(raw, "^[\n\r]*(.-)[\n\r]*$")
    local data = lpegmatch(csv_parser, raw)
    --- map column name -> column nr
    data.header = tableswapped(data.header)
    datasets[id] = data
  end

  --- escaping hell ahead, please ignore.
  local s_item = [[
  \bgroup
    \string\def\string\insert{\string\getvalue{csv_insert_field}{%s}{%s}}%%
%s%% template
  \egroup
]]

  local typeset = function (id, template)
    local data   = datasets[id] or die("ERROR unknown dataset: " .. id)
    template     = stringmatch(buffersraw(template), "^[\n\r]*(.-)[\n\r]*$")
    local result = { }
    local last = \letterhash data
    for i=1, last do
      result[i] = stringformat(s_item, id, i, template)
    end
    context(tableconcat(result))
  end

  local insert = function (id, n, field)
    local this = datasets[id]
    context(this[n][this.header[field]])
  end

  commands.process_csv      = process
  commands.process_csv_file = function (id, fname)
    process(id, ioloaddata(fname, true))
  end
  commands.typeset_csv_job  = typeset
  commands.insert_csv_field = insert

\stopluacode

\startinterface all
  \setinterfaceconstant{template}{template}
  \setinterfaceconstant    {data}{data}
\stopinterface

\def\processcsvbuffer[#id][#buf]{%
  \ctxcommand{process_csv([[#id]], buffers.raw(\!!bs#buf\!!es))}%
}

\def\processcsvfile[#id][#filename]{%
  \ctxcommand{process_csv_file([[#id]], \!!bs\detokenize{#filename}\!!es)}%
}

%% modeled after \startbuffer
\setuvalue{\e!start csvtemplate}{%
  \begingroup
  \obeylines
  \dosingleempty\csv_template_start%
}

\def\csv_template_start[#id]{%
  \buff_start_indeed{}{#id}{\e!start csvtemplate}{\e!stop csvtemplate}%
}

\installnamespace                  {csvjob}
\installcommandhandler \????csvjob {csvjob} \????csvjob

\appendtoks
  \setuevalue{\currentcsvjob}{\csv_job_direct[\currentcsvjob]}
\to \everydefinecsvjob

\unexpanded\def\csv_job_direct[#id]{%
  \edef\currentcsvjob{#id}%
  \dosingleempty\csv_job_indeed%
}

\def\csv_job_indeed[#setups]{%
  \iffirstargument\setupcurrentcsvjob[#setups]\fi
  \ctxcommand{typeset_csv_job(
                [[\csvjobparameter\c!data]],
                [[\csvjobparameter\c!template]])}%
}

\def\csv_insert_field#id#n[#field]{%
  \ctxcommand{insert_csv_field([[#id]], #n, [[#field]])}%
}

\protect

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                               demo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Stepwise instructions.
%% step 1: Define template.
\startcsvtemplate [tpl]
\chapter{\insert[Name]}

You owe \insert[Amount]. Please send it before \insert[Date].
\par
\stopcsvtemplate

%% step 2: Define an input (CSV).
\startbuffer[csdata]
Name,Amount,Date
"Mr. White","\\letterdollar 300","Dec. 2, 1911"
"Mr. Brown","\\letterdollar 300","Dec. 3, 1911"
"Ms. Premise","\\letterdollar 42","Dec. 4, 1911"
"Ms. Conclusion","\\letterdollar 23","Dec. 5, 1911"
\stopbuffer

%% step 3: Parse and store the input.
\processcsvbuffer[one][csdata]
%\processcsvfile[two][test.csv]

%% step 4: Declare a job, joining dataset and template.
\definecsvjob [testing] [
  data=one,
  template=tpl,
]

%% step 5: Enjoy!
\starttext 
  \completecontent
  \testing
\stoptext
```

The above example contains a table of contents, but it will not compile. If I delete `\completecontent`, the document compiles fine.

How can I add a table of contents and headers to my document when it is built from this CSV form letter code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `\expanded` around the `\chapter{...}` call solves your problem.

Inspecting the `.tuc` file shows that chapter titles are written to the chapter list (which is a Lua table) as `"\\insert [Name]"`, i.e. as the unexpanded input. `\expanded{...}` expands its contents (deepest-first); now, `\chapter` only sees the far less problematic `Ms. Premise` (for example).

```
\startcsvtemplate [tpl]
  % \chapter{\insert[Name]}}  %% doesn't work
  \expanded{\chapter{\insert[Name]}}

  You owe \insert[Amount]. Please send it before \insert[Date].
  \par
\stopcsvtemplate
```

Deeper explanation: expanding `\insert[Name]` inside the template gets you the desired name. Exporting the same code outside the template (by writing it to a list that gets used elsewhere, and expanding it there) gets you an error.