# Test whether CSV field is empty or not (ConteXt)

Tags: context

I am designing an address book using the CSV parser in [How to create form letters from spreadsheet data in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72735/how-to-create-form-letters-from-spreadsheet-data-in-context). Some persons have an academic title, while others not. Some also have a job address, others not. My layout depends on whether these data fields contain information or not. I can't figure out how to test, if a CSV field is empty or not. My first idea was to use something like `\doifnotempty{\expanded{\insert[acadtitle]}{(\insert[acadtitle])}`, but that always executes the command regardless whether the field is empty or not. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Try \ifx\@empty#1 where #1 is what you are testing.  Don't forget the \makeatletter ... \makeatother.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am using ConTeXt. How could I achieve this with the `\doif` commands?

Comment: No idea.  But the etoolbox package has \ifdefempty which is supposed to do the same thing.

Comment: If `\insert` is an expandable command then `\doifnotempty{\insert[acadtitle]}` should work (no need to `\expand`). If it is unexpandable, then you can try `\doiftextelse{\insert[acadtitle]}{true}{false}`. If these don't work, then please post a minimal working example.

Comment: `\doiftextelse{\expanded{\insert[AcademicTitle]}}{
\insert[AcademicTitle] \insert[Name]\\
}{}`works. The issue was that I used `AcademicTitle` with a leading space as column name in the CSV data. :-(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was apparently caused by a malformatted CSV file.